# Javascript floodlight tracking iframe leaves browser window blank, please help!

Tags: javascript, pdf, onclick, spotlight, document.write

I have been asked to implement a javascript floodlight tag onto my site which is to be called everytime a customer downloads a pdf file. I have tried to implement this as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function appForm() {
 var axel = Math.random() + "";
 var a = axel * 10000000000000;
 document.write('<IFRAME SRC="http://fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=1234567;type=count123;cat=123do456;ord=1;num='+ a + '?" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 FRAMEBORDER=0></IFRAME>');
 return false;
}
</script>
<a href="appForm.pdf" target="_blank" onClick="appForm();">Download PDF</a>
```

This seems to almost work. The pdf file opens in a new window. But the window where you clicked the download link turns blank. Is there a way of opening this tracking iframe and then having the pdf opening without the parent window going blank? Your help will be very much appreciated on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.write() can't be reliably used after the page has loaded. Use the more modern `document.createElement` function and its friends:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://...");
iframe.setAttribute("width", "1");
iframe.setAttribute("height", "1");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

(untested, but seems like it should work...)